# Could not connect to SMTP host. Message could not be sent

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

When I sent email from server then it gives me two error -

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message could not be sent.
>   Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

I found many hints on another answers on Stack overflow but doesn't work. I tried port no 465/587/65. Even below code works proper on my local system If i set port 587. But in server, It doesn't work.

```
require('class.phpmailer.php');
require('class.smtp.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();      
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->Username = "FromEmailId";
$mail->Password = "Password"; 
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->From = "FromEmailId";
$mail->AddAddress("ToEmail");      
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  
$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
echo "Message has been sent";
```

Comment: i think this is server side error

Comment: @Yogesh. Thanks for replying. But how can i solve it.?

Comment: dear i m also facing this problem ,but not geting any solution

Comment: What kind of host are you on? They might have out-going SMTP blocked (*I know this is a thing as one of the hosts I use for VPS's blocks all outgoing SMTP, I have to ask them to unblock it for specific instances.*).

Comment: Can you test this with data you surely know to be correct? Can you test this with other SMTP servers like yahoo as well?

Comment: @PuneetChawla know check my answer and run the code ....in my case its working perfectly

Comment: You're using GoDaddy, which blocks outbound SMTP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer on godaddy server, setup correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984352/phpmailer-on-godaddy-server-setup-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Try phpmailer in debug mode to check the error

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;       // Enable verbose debug output
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Out of the answers posted, this is the only one going in the right direction, but it should be a comment.

Comment: @Synchro Agree with you. This simple line help you to debug phpmailer. It basically gives verbose error to help you trace the bug or error.

Comment: Thanks for replying Ranjeet. I discussed with my friend and he told, there is a need to do some setting on godaddy server (configuration email). That's why It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

First logout the your gmail account

then open this url
[use this yrl](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

[image]

click the continue button

**Next**
change the port and SMTPsecure

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Yogesh. I discussed with my friend and he told, there is a need to do some setting on godaddy server (configuration email). That's why It's not working. I tried by changing SMTPSecure and Port but it doesn't work.

Comment: @PuneetChawla try to  this process once ...because in my case same problem  i get ,but using this process i am send mail without any error

Comment: Okay yogesh. I will try as soon as possible and will let you know surely.

Comment: This will not work; the problem is that the OP is on GoDaddy, it's nothing to do with google settings.

Comment: @Synchro i know that but in my case its working perfectly :)

Comment: That's irrelevant. It's not you asking the question.

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati - I have tried yogesh. It's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail Help :

> Still can't send mail?
>
> If you tried configuring your SMTP server on port 465 (with SSL/TLS) and port 587 (with STARTTLS), but are still having trouble sending mail, try configuring your SMTP to use port 25 (with SSL/TLS).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried 465/587/25 but no one works.

Comment: try to connection smtp link in server,  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775    the last answer

Answer (score 0):

This question failed to do a basic search and missed a vital piece of information later mentioned in comments: **the OP is using GoDaddy**. GoDaddy is well known to block outbound SMTP, so any suggestions relating to switching port numbers or security protocols will not help. You need to read [other questions on GoDaddy's mail handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984352/phpmailer-on-godaddy-server-setup-correctly), and read their support documentation, which will push you in the direction of using GoDaddy's mail servers (using `securehosting` domains) or via localhost as a relay to the same. All of this is also covered in the [PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

In future, search before posting, as per the [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).